# Do you need to set your network profile as Public or Private when creating your own hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, ubuntu, windows, node-js

I want to create a Nodejs server on my laptop using my ISP. I have a broadband connection and  router. I have WSL Ubuntu installed on Windows 10.

I don't need to do anything commercially or for business purpose. I just want to test it.

Basically, I need to access this server from any other network using my public IP.

Now I paid attention to this - Windows 10 Wi Fi settings:

[image]

So now I want to know if I set it as *Private*, would it work as desired? Or I must make it *Public* so someone can access it using my network's public IP?

PS: I know I also have to do port forwarding, firewall settings. But first I want to figure out this *Public* and *Private* profile. I'm not sure which one do I need to use for this purpose.

Comment: Where are you seeing those options?  Is that on your router, part of Ubuntu, or part of the web server?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller [It's a network setting built into Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d)

Comment: Then why the tag [tag:ubuntu]???

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it's in Windows 10 Wi Fi settings. But it's in all common Windows editions basically. Windows 7, 10, 11 etc. The server is running on WSL (Ubuntu).

Comment: This setting does not impact TCP/IP access to your computer, it's for Windows discoverability and file & printer sharing network protocols (i.e., connecting to a shared folder/drive or printer from another Windows computer). Running a web server will not be affected by this setting, so selecting "Private" is just fine. The only consideration is making sure the port(s) for your web server (e.g., Node.js) are open in your firewall and that those ports are forwarded by your router to your computer's internal/private IP address, as you indicated you were already aware of.

Comment: @dan Thanks. You may want to add it as an answer?

Comment: No problem. Feel free to add it as an answer and then accept it when you can - that will help to build some reputation for yourself here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find any other resource about it but I found answer in the comments of my question. I would like to post it as an answer below:

This setting does not impact TCP/IP access to your computer, it's for Windows discoverability and file & printer sharing network protocols (i.e., connecting to a shared folder/drive or printer from another Windows computer). Running a web server will not be affected by this setting, so selecting "Private" is just fine. The only consideration is making sure the port(s) for your web server (e.g., Node.js) are open in your firewall and that those ports are forwarded by your router to your computer's internal/private IP address, as you indicated you were already aware of.